# Can I store function in key-value pair where the function is the key for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, functional-programming

I have a list of functions as below

```
function max(result, current) {
    if (result > current) return result
    else return current
}

function min(result, current) {
    if (result < current) return result
    else return current
}

function sum(result, current) {
    return result + current
}

function product(result, current) {
    return result * current
}
```

I can store them in an array as below

```
const mapOfFunctions = [
    sum,
    product,
    max,
    min,
]
```

But can I store them as a key-value pair, where the function is the key?

```
const mapOfFunctions = [
    {sum: 0},
    {product: 1},
    {max: Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER},
    {min: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER},
]
```

Comment: This sounds awfully like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is the goal here? You cannot use the functions themselves as object keys since object keys are implicitly strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) class lets you use any object as a key:

```
const identities = new Map([
  [sum, 0],
  [product, 1],
  [max, Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER],
  [min, Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER]
]);

const sumIdentity = identities.get(sum); // 0
const productIdentity = identities.get(product); // 1
```

Comment: Great! How could I miss though about the `[]`

Comment: Here's the docs for Map; its constructor can take an iterable of key/value tuples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map